# Is it possible to add a specific screen resolution option (i.e. 1720 x 1440) to windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, screen-resolution

I have two widescreen curved monitors (optimal resolution 3440 x 1440) with the option to split each screen into two independent displays with their own media source.

I would like to use this functionality for one of my screens but because the appropriate screen resolution (i.e. 1720 x 1440) is not available the result is that Windows is being stretched.

Is it possible to add screen resolutions to the default Windows list (i.e. via regedit) or is there an application which enables me to adjust it integrally?

My graphic card is Intel® HD Graphics 4600.

Answer (score 0):

I used this tool with my AMD 7970 and it worked great.

http://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU

Add it as a detailed resolution, restart machine, pick it from Screen Resolution options and off you go.